# What is the lower bound of sorting algorithm in RAM model?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm writing C# code and to analyse an algorithm I'm using RAM or Pointer model of computation.

I know that if we choose decision tree model we can prove that the lower bound of `sorting algorithm` is `Ω(nlogn)`. A decision tree is a full binary tree that represents the comparisons between elements that are performed by a particular sorting algorithm operating on an input of a given size. Control, data movement, and all other aspects of the algorithm are ignored.

But nobody works in this `tree model`, all of us use the RAM or the Pointer machine to analyse performance of an algorithm.

What is the lower bound of sorting algorithm in RAM/Pointer model?

Comment: It's safe to say that any sorting algorithm on any model is Ω(n), because you can't know whether a list is sorted without looking at each element at least once.

Comment: Agree with @user3386109, here's [a Khan Academy discussion on how Insertion Sort is Ω(n) for an already sorted list](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/insertion-sort/a/analysis-of-insertion-sort)

Comment: It's like to say that bubble sort works 0(n^100)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about computing theory, not programming. Perhaps cs.stackexchange.com would be a better venue.

Comment: It's not about theory! It's about real world sorting complexity. I mean theory said that its NLOGN, but I would like to know more realistic value

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms

Comment: Real world machines have very little in common with the RAM model, due to the hierarchical memory arrangement. Because of it, it is probably more realistic to consider an exponential behavior O(a^N).

Comment: I think this is a great question (although probably more suited for CS). Ivan: one issue you'll have is that nailing down what a RAM/pointer machine actually _is_ is difficult -- it's easy to make a RAM/pointer machine that can access only a finite amount of memory (so the question of big-O becomes meaningless). And if you make it more powerful, it's possible to sort in better than O(n log n). I investigated this question a while ago, and my summary's on my blog here: http://paulhankin.github.io/Complexity/